# IF operations on variables

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I'm building a script in bash for use on Linux (SLES 11SP3). I'd like to check whether a certain process exists by looking up it's pid using this syntax:

```
pid="$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep /sbin/syslog-ng | awk '{print $2}')"
```

This fills variable pid with the pid of the syslog-ng process. Then I want to use this variable in an if statement:

```
if [ ${pid} > 0 ]; then
  do something
else
  do something else
fi
```

The problem is that this if statement seems to always be false, even if the variable pid has a value higher than 0. So, the else part is always executed instead of the correct (if condition is true) statement.

I had a similar issue with the use of wc -l to check the existence of filesystems:

```
exist_tmp=$(df -x fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon -h | grep /tmp | wc -l)
if [ ${exist_tmp} > 0 ]; then
  do something
fi
```

This would not work, even if the variable has a value of 1, indicating the existence of a /tmp filesystem. It started working (or at least doing what I wanted it to do), when I changed the syntax to this:

```
if [ ${exist_tmp} != 0 ]; then
  do something
fi
```

The difference between greater than 0 and not equal to 0 eludes me a bit in this used case.

The questions therefor are:

1. Does anybody have an idea why the pid lookup and if statement won't do what I want it to do?
2. Does anybody have an idea what the problem with the > 0 and != 0 might have been?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try -gt instead of > the former compares integers, the latter strings.

Comment: pgrep can help you to reduce your script

Comment: `[` is a command.  `>` is a redirection.  `cmd argument > 0` redirects the output of cmd to a file named `0`..  So does `[ ${exist_tmp} > 0 ]`

Answer (score 3):

With bash, comparisons like <, >, != are for comparing strings lexicographically. To compare their integer values, you do > like this:

```
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]
```

and inequality like this:

```
if [ "$a" -ne "$b" ]
```

See [this reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for more detail or other comparators.

Comment: So, anything coming from "wc -l" or a grep of a process ID should be compared with the "-gt" and "-ne" type operators? The ones I used are for string comparison.

Comment: That's right. To clarify, all bash values are strings — but if your string contains only digits and you want to compare its integer value, you should use -gt, -ne, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep /sbin/syslog-ng | awk '{print $2}'` can evaluate to multiple lines. You need to pick one of them. To pick the first one, append `head -n 1`:

```
... | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1
```

The second example works because `wc -l` always returns one number on a single line.

Comment: I've noticed a strange thing: while `pid=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep /sbin/syslog-ng | awk '{print $2}')` will work from the command prompt (if I `echo $pid` it will give me a number), it will return an empty variable when used in the script (saw this when I traced the part where this variable is filled). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare integers, better use arithmetic if statement:

```
if (( pid > 0 )); then
  do something
else
  do something else
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to get process PIDs is to use `pgrep`.

```
pid=$(pgrep -fo /sbin/syslog-ng)     # oldest
pid=$(pgrep -fn /sbin/syslog-ng)     # newest
pids=($(pgrep -f /sbin/syslog-ng))   # an array of pids
```

If there might be more than one process running you should use `-o` or `-n` to select the oldest or newest process, respectively. Or you could change your script to save and work with all the PIDs.

Then to compare numbers you should either use `-gt` and `-lt` with square brackets, or switch to `((...))` which is designed for arithmetic comparisons.

```
if ((pid > 0))         # great
if [[ $pid -gt 0 ]]    # good
if [ "$pid" -gt 0 ]    # meh
```

If you went with the array approach then you would loop over all the PIDs.

```
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

---

In fact, if your goal is simply to test for a process's existence, you can skip getting the PID and test `pgrep`'s exit code.

```
if pgrep -f /sbin/syslog-ng > /dev/null; then
    # process exists
fi
```